# Creating edges in Arango WebUI

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to add edges directly from the Arango WebUI-Graphs interface.
However, the interface complaints that:

```
Could not create edge: edge collection not used in graph
```

I'm actually using an edge collection in my graph, so it is unclear how to troubleshoot this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with the web interface, and has been fixed in `v3.5.0`.
If you are not able to update to this version, you can create edges directly through the AQL interface:

```
<code>INSERT {
  _from: "collection/vertex-id",
  _to: "collection/vertex-id",
  &lt;your-other-properties&gt;
} INTO &lt;your-edge-collection&gt;
</code>
```